# Eliminar una llave foranea de una tabla hija

Tags: mysql, sql

En **mysql Workbench** tengo tres tablas:

- Tabla pedidos: Id_pedido PK, Id_cliente FK, Id_vendedor FK, Id_producto FK.
- Tabla productos: Id_producto PK
- Tabla pedidos_productos; Id_pedidos_productos PK, id_pedidos FK, Id_producto FK.
  (existe columnas extras pero no van al caso ya que no son ni pk ni fk).

Estoy intentando eliminar la **fk**, "*id_producto*" de la *tabla pedidos*, pero me salta error.

Aclaro que en la *tabla productos* ya tengo datos cargados.

Ya probe con `foreign_key_checks = 0`, y luego intentar eliminar no me lo permite.

`ALTER TABLE pedidos drop foreign key id_producto;ALTER TABLE pedidos drop constraint id_producto;`

Probe con esas dos querys y me da los siguientes errores respectivamente:

> Error Code: 1091. Can't DROP 'id_producto'; check that column/key
> exists Error Code: 3940. Constraint 'id_producto' does not exist.

Comment: Pásanos tu dataset en SQL con phpmyadmin, exportar, para intentar reproducir la situación. Aunque tiene toda la pinta de que tienes datos que no existen en tu tabla de referencia y por eso no te deja crear la FK

Comment: @DavidJP no quiere crearla.. quiere eliminarla...

Comment: Estas seguro que no la eliminaste ya?

Comment: @gbianchi Tienes razón, quiere eliminar y parece que ya la ha eliminado y el error lo obtiene al intentar eliminar algo ya eliminado

Comment: ya lo solucione. Revise la informacion de la tabla, en la pestaña de DDL, y ahi te figura al final luego de KEY, CONSTRAINT 'Y EL NOMBRE DE LA FK' (que no es el mismo cual vos la nombraste. luego utilizando la misma query que venia utilizando pero remplazando el nombre por el que sale en la descripcion de la tabla en la pestaña DDL.